# Returning a nested array type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

This question is much more academic than practical.

I have a function `filledArray(val, ...dims)`, which takes a fill value and a variable number of dimensions, and builds a nested multidimensional array filled with that value, to the specification in the dimensions. For example:

```
> filledArray('x', 5)
[ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ]

> filledArray('x', 2, 5)
[ [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ],
  [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ], ]

> filledArray('x', 2, 5, 1)
[ [ [ 'x' ], [ 'x' ], [ 'x' ], [ 'x' ], [ 'x' ] ],
  [ [ 'x' ], [ 'x' ], [ 'x' ], [ 'x' ], [ 'x' ] ] ]
```

Typescript infers that the return type of this function is `any`. Can the true return type be expressed in the type system somehow, so that the three return values above are correctly typed as `string[]`, `string[][]`, and `string[][][]`? (And so on, for deeper and deeper arrays?)

A sample implementation of this function:

```js
function filledArray<T>(val: T, ...dims: number[]) {
    if (dims.length == 0)
        return val

    let [dim, ...rest] = dims
    return Array.from(Array(dim), _ => filledArray(val, ...rest))
}
```

Interestingly, it even seems like specifying a fixed number of overload declarations seems to make the final `...rest` in the function somehow be of the wrong type...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646270/declare-arbitrarily-nested-array-recursive-type-definition

Comment: Not sure you can get a type that has a explicit depth, but you can create a recursive array type like this: `type RecursiveArray<T> = Array<T | RecursiveArray<T>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a return type can be expressed with a recursive conditional type.

```
type FilledArray<N extends number[], T> = 
  N extends [number, ...infer Rest extends number[]]
    ? FilledArray<Rest, T>[]
    : T

function filledArray<T, N extends number[]>(val: T, ...dims: N): FilledArray<N, T> {
  if (dims.length == 0)
    return val as unknown as FilledArray<N, T>

  let [dim, ...rest] = dims
  return Array.from(Array(dim), _ => filledArray(val, ...rest)) as FilledArray<N, T>
}
```

We can recursively check how many numbers the `dims` tuple holds and add a `[]` to the return type for each number.

The first conditional `N extends [number, ...infer Rest extends number[]]` checks if there is still at least one element in the tuple `N` and simultaneously stores every element except the first one in the inferred type `Rest`. `Rest` might also be an empty tuple if there are no more elements. If the conditional is true, we call the type recursively with `Rest` and add a `[]` to the end of it. If the conditional is false, we can return the type `T` to end the recursion.

Since TypeScript does not understand how conditional return types relate to the function implementation, we have to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) for the returned values.

Here are some tests:

```
const a = filledArray('x', 5)
// const a: "x"[]

const b = filledArray('x', 2, 5)
// const b: "x"[][]

const c = filledArray(0, 2, 5, 1)
// const c: 0[][][]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAZgSwDYYKYBMCCAToXAJ4AUA5AB6UA0MArAJQBQA9OzKJLHAFwwARNSEBtALqtWPaDABGSVJhwFiZKrQYAmBiw5dZseYJHiJk6Ue5L0WPERIUADDr0MAjG07dwc4ILOksFS0lCkAA7YMABiKg7qpAA8AHIw2NRQ2GC4EDBgAK4AtvLYhJIMACoAfEqsMDBpGVk5eWKFJWUMAHS9aGAoZTAASthyzdm5+cWl5RJSDQ0A-LHxak5Jo9BV1ZaLMIKV0igFYMBQaODK9utkSZUMTZmTeR2zktXkAG5wGIc9vVwaCKEEEKWYgjiN0cdxSOxgAG96jA0CgYOQgSDujgwABzKAACyQyGcbH2hGwUAKhDAMB+GHgeVOAGswCAAO60uB5KGqGHJOEwGrSBo4WBiTEA7oU6ASJSYiDIilUmkwfndFCEEBFcj8jHA5gMAD6SFqdj5iW+vylMqgzGYjNW0MSqR2rAAvkA)

Comment: Amazing! I must admit I'm having trouble reading the definition of the `FilledArray` type, especially the part `[number, ...infer Rest extends number[]]`. Could you explain a little more about what that is doing please?

Comment: @Joppy I added an explanation :)